# Cannot access SSH after modifying sshd_config file in Google Cloud Ubuntu Server

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04, google-compute-engine

I added the following lines to the 'sshd_config' file in Ubuntu Server hosted in my Google Cloud and now i cannot SSH to my Ubuntu Server. 
I get network timeout error in the SSH window in Google Cloud Console: **Connection Failed
We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue.**

---

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
# This section must be placed at the very end of sshd_config
Match Group sftponly
ChrootDirectory /SFTP
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

---

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can undo the changes you made by accessing the failing instance via the Serial Console and undo the edit to the  'sshd_config' file. Steps are as follows:

1. Go to the VM instances page in Google Cloud Platform console
2. Click on the instance affected. The instance for which you want to add a startup script
3. Enable the option ‘Enable connecting to serial ports’
4. Click the ‘Edit’ button at the top of the page
5. Under ‘Custom metadata’, click ‘Add item’
6. Set the 'Key' to 'startup-script' and set the 'Value' to this script: #! /bin/bash useradd -G google-sudoers USERNAME echo 'USERNAME:PASSWORD' | chpasswd 
   7.Please note that you will have to replace the words “USERNAME” and “PASSWORD” with your own username and password
7. Click Save and then click RESET at the top of the page. You might need to wait for some time for the instance to reboot
8. Click on 'Connect to serial port' in the page
9. In the new window, you might need to wait a bit and press on Enter of your keyboard once; then, you should see the login prompt
10. Login using the USERNAME and PASSWORD you provided and undo the changes you made to the file